# How does this SMS Passcode screen work?

Tags: security, iphone, ios

While doing a particular login using my mobile phone number, a SMS Passcode is sent, and then displayed like this on my iPhone:

[image: Screenshot]

How does it work? Is it an SMS generated with some metadata that the iPhone shows differently for security reasons (you don't want a passcode saved in your SMS inbox)?

I've searched a lot, but I couldn't find any information about such screens.

Comment: Why don't my banks do this? It's so annoying to manually delete those OTP messages. If they could "flash" and destroy themselves once I used them, that would be great... `</rant>`

Comment: I don't understand the "too broad" reason to put this on hold. It's clear, has a screenshot, and has just **one short answer** which is correct. So there aren't "too many possible answers" or a possibility of having "good answers would be too long".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an iPhone, but it's probably a so-called [Flash SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service#Flash_SMS).

Comment: Thanks, yea must be flash sms. Now to the "how to send flash sms" research.

Comment: Should be plenty floating around, considering the [Android bug](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/29/sms-vulnerability-in-nexus-devices-can-be-exploited-to-force-a-reboot-or-kill-cellular-connectivity/).